# What is the exact meaning of these Bootstrap col classes set on a div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am pretty new to Bootstrap and I have the following question related to this code found on a tutorial:

```
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          <div class="panel price panel-grey">
            <div class="panel-heading arrow_box text-center">
              <h3>Simple Plan</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body text-center">
              <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px;"><strong>$8.99 / month</strong>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
              <li class="list-group-item">1 Free Domain</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">5GB Disk Space</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">25GB Bandwidth</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">20 Email Accounts</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="panel-footer">
              <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

As you can see in the previous code snippet, the main div was set with the following classes: **col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3**

Reading online, it seems to me that these classes are related to the screen dimension (**xs: extra small, **sm**: small, **ms**: medium, **lg**: large).

But what is the exact meaning of these classes set on the main div? What is the final effect on rendering?

Comment: The manual explains: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Is the basic idea about grid System

**.col-md-4**
Get three equal-width columns starting at desktops and scaling to large desktops. On mobile devices, tablets and below, the columns will automatically stack.

**.col-md-3 /  .col-md-6  / .col-md-3**
Get three columns starting at desktops and scaling to large desktops of various widths.Grid columns should add up to twelve for a single horizontal block. More than that, and columns start stacking no matter the viewport.

**.col-md-8 /  .col-md-4**
Get two columns starting at desktops and scaling to large desktops.

For more Information :- http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 1):

So, if you have something like this:

```
col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3
```

This is what it would do:

- `col-xs-6` will make that element take half of the horizontal screen space on smartphones.
- `col-sm-6` will make that element take half of the horizontal screen space on tablet devices.
- `col-md-3` will take one fourth of the screen on medium devices (laptops and desktops with small screen resolutions or large tablets)
- `col-lg-3` will take one fourth of the screen on large devices (laptops and desktops with large screen resolutions)

Now there is a problem with that line in whatever tutorial you're using.

If you type in `col-xs-6` and nothing more, the element will take half of the width of the screen on all devices. If you add `col-md-3` right next to it, it will take half of the screen on extrasmall and small screens, but it will take one fourth of the screen on medium and large screens.

With that being said, it's really unnecessary to type `col-sm-6` and `col-lg-3`. You can delete those two classes from the `div` element and this won't change a thing.